# How to disable sorting on column in jQuery.tablesorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I try to find a way how to disable sorting on column. I use jQuery plugin [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). And by default if you click on header cell it sort column data, but what I need to do if I don't need to use sorting on one or two column in four columns table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You must pass the appropriate parameters at initialization, for example:

```
{ ...
   headers: { 0: { sorter: false} }
}
```

For more information, check the manual at:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: best way, don't go with overwriting classes and stuff. It's cleaner. If you want to keep the arrows try to re-use the css from the lib

Comment: This is only a partial answer. It disables sorting but not tablesorter for this column, it continues to wrap our content in their sh*** box. Since this plugin is removing DOM element, i cant bind events on it.

Answer (score 22):

Also you can use html data attribute:

```
<th data-sorter="false">...</th>
```

Or you can use a class:

```
<th class="sorter-false">...</th>
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
$('#selector').tablesorter({headers: {0: { sorter: false}}});
```

This is clearly outlined here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
            1: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
            2: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/css/theme.blue.min.css' type='text/css' />
<table id='myTable' cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter-blue">             
    <thead>> 
        <tr> 
            <th>first name</th> 
            <th>last name</th> 
            <th>age</th> 
            <th>total</th> 
            <th>discount</th> 
            <th>date</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>peter</td> 
            <td>parker</td> 
            <td>28</td> 
            <td>$9.99</td> 
            <td>20%</td> 
            <td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>john</td> 
            <td>hood</td> 
            <td>33</td> 
            <td>$19.99</td> 
            <td>25%</td> 
            <td>dec 10, 2002 5:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>clark</td> 
            <td>kent</td> 
            <td>18</td> 
            <td>$15.89</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 12, 2003 11:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>bruce</td> 
            <td>almighty</td> 
            <td>45</td> 
            <td>$153.19</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2001 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>bruce</td> 
            <td>evans</td> 
            <td>22</td> 
            <td>$13.19</td> 
            <td>11%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2007 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

For single column xpapad is right

For multiple columns disabling sortings

headers: { 0: { sorter: false}, 1: {sorter: false}, 2: {sorter: false} }

http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration

Answer (score 0):

In **tablesorter v2.18.1**, you can now target a column by the class name of an element inside of a header; note that the span has the targeted class name in the first name column.

HTML

```
 <table class="tablesorter">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th><span class="first-name">First Name</span></th>
     ...
```

JS

```
  $("table").tablesorter({
     headers: {
       '.first-name' : {
       sorter: false
     }
   }
 });
```

In **tablesorter v2.0.5** and older, only the metadata and headers options methods were available.

In **versions 2.3+**, columns can be disabled using any of the following methods (they all do the same thing), in order of priority:

- jQuery data `data-sorter="false"`.

  ```
  <table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <th data-sorter="false">Age</th>
             ....
  ```
- metadata `class="{ sorter: false }"`. (This requires the metadata plugin)
- headers option `headers : { 0 : { sorter: false } }`.

  ```
  $("table").tablesorter({
      headers : { 0 : { sorter: false } 
  })
  ```
- header class name `class="sorter-false"`.

  ```
  <table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <th class="sorter-false">Discount</th>
             ....
  ```
- disable a column using jQuery data directly, but do it before the table initializes.

  ```
  $("table thead th:eq(5)").data("sorter", false); 
  $("table").tablesorter(
  ```

Answer (score 0):

FOOTABLE.js

The only solution I found working was :

to stop sorting : `$('th').unbind();`
to start sorting : `$('table').trigger('footable_initialize');`